# WPF GroupBox Custom Header Alignment Left And Right

Tags: wpf, groupbox

I am trying to add content to a groupbox header, so that part of the content aligns to the left and the other part aligns to the right.

I've tried adding a grid as the content to the header with 2 columns, but everything aligns left.  I want column 1 to align left, and column 2 to align on the right side of the group box.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, which size the tab-header should use. You can define your header as described and set minumum width for your Grid. This would probably have the effect you're looking for.

```
<Grid MinWidth="250">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <TextBlock Text="Test on the left"/>

  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Right" HorizontalAligment="Right" />

</Grid>
```

More influence for the optical style of GroupBox you can get through the [HeaderTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.headertemplate.aspx) and the [Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744748.aspx)-property.

Comment: I guess this will work, I wanted to try and avoid setting a hardcoded width but I don't see much way around it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a this and if I understand your problem correctly I got it working. I just used textblocks:

```
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefintion />
                <ColumnDefintion />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Blah1" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Blah2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: lol I noticed, :) I was thinking "rats, I was so close too!" :P

Comment: I do realize that this 'aligns' the text to the right, it doesn't actually set the text to the far right of the group header.